# Windows 10 IoT not updating with windows update

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, update

Why is my windows update stuck on downloading updates? How do I kick it along?

From the apps menu I select `Windows Update` tile.

I then have the following screen which I have left on overnight and have attempted the update a number of times with rebooting.

```
Windows Update
Last Checked: 2018-09-30 at 9:53
Last Updated: [empty]
Update State: Update in progress
Status Message: Downloading updates.
```

It the same message each time and stays that way the entire time. 
The device has internet access.

```
OS Info
Computer Name: iot-1
Language: en-US
OS Edition: IoTAP
OS Edition ID: 123
OS Version: 17134.1.armfre.rs4_release.18410-1804
Platform: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
```

Logs: I click the Logs tile but nothing is listed.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with downloads... Again it could be the infamous SD card problem that causes most software issues on the Pi. What I mean the SD cards seems to die allot with random cards. Best cards I ever used where the Samsung ones.. but you need to verify they are not fakes too.. Its a nightmare.

Comment: good tip. I will try another SD card